# How to associate tf model predictions with layers?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

We are working on our `Tensorflow` AI `Sequential model`, which has arrays of data on input and provides probabilities of "true" or "false" on the predictions.

**We want to know which prediction corresponds to 'true' and which to 'false'**

our model:

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([                  
        layers..
        tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D(),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, activation='softmax')
    ])
```

model compile:

```
model.compile(loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy",
                  optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(),
                  metrics=['accuracy']
                  )
```

Then the *model* fits with *tests* and *results*, where **results** is either 'true' or 'false'.

```
history = self.model.fit(
        np.array(self.data["tests"], dtype=float),
        np.array(self.data["results"], dtype=float),
        validation_split=0.1,
        epochs=self.epochs,
        batch_size=self.batch_size,
        steps_per_epoch=self.steps_per_epoch,
        verbose=0,
        shuffle=True,
        callbacks=[PlotLossesKerasTF()],
    )
```

When we make predictions on a new data we use `model.predict(newData)`, it gives us probabilities like:

```
[[0.5787903  0.42120975]]
```

**So which of those numbers correspond to which label?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the same as your training labels.

Consider you have an input image and you classify whether it is a cat, dog or a bird. Your training data is then an array of images and corresponding labels in format of `[cat dog bird]` so for example - an image of dog labeled `[0 1 0]`. So `model.predict(image)` outputs array of probabilities in the same format `[cat dog bird]` so `output[0]` is the probability of cat classification and so forth.

Also if your output is True/False consider using one neuron output with sigmoid activation and binary cross-entropy as your loss function.

Comment: if I had e.x. 3 labes with results [2, 5, 10], then my predictions would be `prediction[2]`, `prediction[5]` or `prediction[10]`, or is it sorted from lowest to higher?

Comment: I edited my answer. Hope it clarifies any confusion.